# File upload in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, wav

i try to upalod `wav` file using codeigniter.
But i have get this error message; 
`The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Code Shown below:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = getwdir() . 'voices/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'wav|mp3';
    $config['max_size'] = 2800000;
    $config['file_name'] = rand();
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    var_dump($config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        var_dump('uploaded');
    }else{
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
    }

var_dump($_FILES['file']);

  array (size=1)
 'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'blob' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'audio/wav' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpe2SQi5' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 98348
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

### View HTML

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/your_controller/do_upload" >
<input type="file" name="fileForUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

### Controller

```
    <?php 
public function do_upload(){
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './path_from_root_to_dir/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; //'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
    //$config['max_size'] = 100;
    //$config['max_width'] = 1024;
    //$config['max_height'] = 768;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('fileForUpload')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //Action, in case file upload failed
    } else {
        //Action, after file successfully uploaded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the upload library with these config values:

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'wav';
$config['max_size'] = '1000000';
$this->load->library('upload', $config).
```

If you attempt to upload a .wav file (tested in firefox 7.0.1).
It will report an error of 'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.'.

> This can be solved by replacing line 68 in
>   application/config/mimes.php

```
'wav' => 'audio/x-wav'
 with:
'wav' => array('audio/wav', 'audio/wave', 'audio/x-wav'),
```

Ok If you Tried it already then try this:

You could try looking at system/libraries/Upload.php line 199:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
```

Change to

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

Then do upload your .wmv file. It would show something like application/octet-stream or whatever. Add that to your mimes.php.

Some Userfull links:

[link1](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/15872/14863/mimetype-corruption-in-firefox.html) , [Link2](http://weblog.philringnalda.com/2004/04/06/getting-around-ies-mime-type-mangling)

Comment: i tried your updated answer. unfortunatly got error.